# How to find a 'Key Word' within a <td> that contains a string

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a script that is checking hardware enclosures and searches table cells for words like Warning, Error and Degraded. Now I would like to also search the log output that pipes out full messages in another column/cell. Specifically I'm looking for the same words within a string. If these are found then a stoplight button is displayed. How do I tweak this script to search a table cell `<td>` for Error when it contains a message something like this: "Error enclosure power supply is unplugged."

I want to include the stoplights there as well because it is relatively easy to overlook the data.

```
<script>
var td = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('td'));
td.forEach(function(td) {
  if(td.innerHTML == 'Warning') {
    td.innerHTML = "Warning" + '<button class="red_stoplight"></button>';
       }
    if(td.innerHTML == 'Error') {
     td.innerHTML = 'Error' + " " + '<button class="yellow_stoplight"></button>';
         }
        if(td.innerHTML == 'Degraded') {
            td.innerHTML = 'Degraded' + " " + '<button class="orange_stoplight"></button>';
            }

  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (td.innerHTML == 'Error')
```

Try:

```
if (td.innerHTML.indexOf('Error') != -1) {
```

That will check if the text "Warning" appears anywhere inside td.innerHTML.

Comment: This will work. At first I thought this would only return the position of the 'word' as an integer. Thanks so much!

Comment: It would return the position as an integer, or -1 if it's not found at all. You're welcome :)